# Building breadcrumbs in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, menu, breadcrumbs

I'm creating a website and have successfully got my navigation Menu working using a tree structure stored in a database.

A `Menu` object as a `active` property, but I don't know how to go about setting it to active! If I can do that, then I can get the path of the currently active `Menu` and render the breadcrumbs using WhiteOctober's BreadcrumbsBundle or something similar.

I've read tons of questions on SO, and also looked at the different bundles available, but I'm still stuck on how to do this.

How would I go about finding out menu item to set as active?

EDIT:

- Menu class: https://gist.github.com/robcaw/c76426957ea6f262d217#file-gistfile1-php
- Menu controller: https://gist.github.com/robcaw/af18e7c0e61f109e9bda#file-gistfile1-php

EDIT 2:

Ok, I've almost done it. I've managed to compare the current path, using `$this->container->get('request')->getPathInfo();` to a `Menu`'s set `url`.

To do this I needed to flatten the menu tree structure into an array. As I'm using the DoctrineExtensions' Tree extension, I used its repository's `getChildren($node)` to do this. So now iterating over the array is easy and can compare the url and path.

In the breadcrumb controller, I can pass the `$current_item` from the menu controller, and again use the Tree repository and its `getPath()` method which recursively gets parents of the given node.

However, there is still a problem, as some pages on the website don't have a menu entry. So for example if I visit `site.com/news/tags/stuff`, there is no menu entry for it and so breaks the site.

So far:

- MenuController: https://gist.github.com/robcaw/61383e26d0a7637bb3f1#file-gistfile1-php
- BreadcrumbController: https://gist.github.com/robcaw/62341672db576fcb2864#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: You want the current active page in your twig template or controller? Can you show us your `Menu` class? (I guess it doesn't only have an `active` property)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't just have that property. The file is over 400 lines so I've added a link to it in the question. The tree structure of the menu works fine, which is why I added the `active` property so I could set the relevant `Menu` item as the active item. I just don't know how to find out the current item!

Comment: I think you will have to compare the `$url` property of your `Menu` object with the current path to do so. Do you have a small example of code showing how you use this `Menu` object in your controller/twig template?

Comment: I've added a link to the menu controller. I have a twig extension which allows me to call `renderMainMenu()` and `renderSideMenu()` within twig templates.

Comment: I have added a `isset($this->current_item)` line 75, try if it helps: https://gist.github.com/cheesemacfly/158f0ae5ff4c83ce6e15 (you need to manage everywhere else where `current_item` is null or return a valid default value in `getCurrentMenuItem()` whatever `$this->current_item` value is

Comment: Thanks for your help. See my answer below as to how I accomplished it finally!

Comment: The [mcve] should contain all code and data as text in the question body.  Questions where vital details are shared via external resources are vulnerable to breakageand becoming useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed it albeit with a lot more code than I thought it would take.

In my header template I call a few custom Twig extensions to render the main menu. In the MenuController, `setCurrentMenuItemAction` is called during the rendering of a menu in order to find out the current menu item. The current menu item needs to be known so that the breadcrumbs can be created. In essence, this method tries to match the current url path (using  `getPathInfo()` to a menu url in the main menu.

The easy part was finding an exact match by just comparing the url and menu urls (I chose not to handle multiple exact matches at this time).

If no exact matches were found, i.e. the url does not match any menus, then it kinda needs to guess what to set as the current item. Firstly, the current url path and menu paths are exploded, I then used a for loop to compare the values of each array:

```
$count = count($url_parts);
//echo $count;
$intersects = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        if(array_key_exists($i, $child_parts)){
        if($child_parts[$i] == $url_parts[$i]){
            //echo $child_parts[$i];
            $intersects++;
        }
    }
}
return $intersects;
```

The returned value is used to calculate which menu item should be the selected one. This gives a similar result to `array_intersect`. The problem with `array_intersect` was that it would compare the arrays regardless of the order the the values were in. For example, say the current url is `/news/tag/sports`, this gives the intersection values of:

Menu item urls:

1. /news **Intersects: 1**
2. /news/general **Intersects: 1**
3. /news/sports **Intersects: 2**

So using `array_intersect`, the url `/news/tag/sports` would result in `/news/sports` being the selected menu. The desired selected menu item would be `/news`, which is why I had to ditch `array_intersect`.

As both menu #1 and #2 above have intersect values of 1, simply finding the menu with the least items its exploded array will give the desired menu.

Finally, if there are still no matches: there is no similararities between the url and any menu item, then a temporary menu must be created. I wanted to create an instance of `Menu` to do this but ran into problems using this with the MenuRepository (I assume it needs a menu needs to be stored in the db), so i just created an array with the current url and the `end()` of the url as the name. Slightly messy - will probably need improving at some point.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Regarding the `array_intersect` issue you have, can you not use [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) instead?